# programmatically manipulate survey list perform add update delete operation

Tags: web-part, 2013, survey-list

I want to create Polling app. For that i want to learn about survey list. That can I add update delete survey list data Programmatically.? First of all i want to create a web part which perform this but I am not able to find any logic according to this on google.

I am trying to search web part which lets me know how to manipulate Survey List?

Answer (score 1):

surveys are just another type of lists, you insert items the same way you do it with normal lists

Here is sample code for manipulate list

```
SPList list = web.Lists["My survey"];
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates =true;
SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
item["This is my question number 1"] = "this is the answer";
item.Update();
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates =false;
```

Hope this helps